# How to plot legends using loop in Axes3D in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following array in Python:

```
numbers=[75, 100, 680, 123, 4, 4, 8, 15]
```

These numbers are corresponding to the amount of points, which are being associated to a certain cluster.

So together with plotting the cluster points I want to have a legend, which is giving following information:

```
"Cluster 1 has 75 points"

"Cluster 2 has 100 points"
```

and so on.

I have difficulties coding the loops, so the help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what kind of plot so you want to do?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I want to have a 3D-plot ot points. Now I`m using the following piece of a code:

    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig1)
    ax.scatter(X_scaled[:,0], X_scaled[:,1],X_scaled[:,7],c=labels, cmap='Set1', s=50)


In X_scaled are saved the coordinates of the cluster points. 


    np.shape(X_scaled)=(800,8)

Comment: add the full code and data

Comment: Actually there is anything else. Just reading the data and applying DBSCAN. Is it now more clear what is the issue?


    min_max_scaler=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    X_scaled=min_max_scaler.fit_transform(data)

    eps=0.28
    min_numbers=3
    dbscan=DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_numbers).fit(X_scaled)
    labels=dbscan.labels_

     fig1 = plt.figure()
     ax = Axes3D(fig1)
     ax.scatter(X_scaled[:,0], X_scaled[:,1],X_scaled[:,7],c=labels, cmap='Set1', s=50)

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **UPDATE:**

After providing more information I think you need this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# random data: 800 samples, 8 coordinates
X_scaled = np.random.rand(800,8)

# some labels e.g. output of clustering algorithm
labels = np.concatenate([np.ones(400),np.zeros(400)])

# unique classes/groups in the data
number_of_classes = np.unique(labels).shape[0]

# the desired legends
legends = ['cluster 1', 'cluster 2']

# colors for the groups
colors = ["r","b"]


fig1 = plt.figure() 
ax = Axes3D(fig1) 

for i in range(number_of_classes):
    ax.scatter(X_scaled[:,0][labels==i], X_scaled[:,1][labels==i],X_scaled[:,7][labels==i], c = colors[i] ,s=50, label= legends[i] + " has {} points".format(X_scaled[:,0][labels==i].shape[0]))

plt.legend()
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi = 300)
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT 1: How to use a for loop to create the legends.

```
legends = []
for i in range(5):
    legends.append('cluster{}'.format(i))

print(legends)
['cluster0', 'cluster1', 'cluster2', 'cluster3', 'cluster4']
```

Comment: It worked fine for me, thanks.I would have one last question. How could one create the array 'legends' with a loop? I tried, but it does not work.....


   legends=[]
   for i in range(5):
       item=['cluster%d' %i].append([i])
       print(legends)

Comment: see my Edit 1 in my answer